# extract superclass from multiple classes and derive from it

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I want to refactor multiple classes that I think should derive from one base class.

How to properly accomplish this refactoring using ReSharper 6 ? I can extract superclass from one of the classes, but what next? Do I have to manually then derive from this base class and search for same members in every class I want to be derived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run all of your unit tests and see that they pass
2. Extract the base class from one of your classes. Call it `BaseClass` or something
3. Run all of your unit tests ...
4. Extract the base class from another of your classes. Call it `BaseClass2` or something
5. Run all of your unit tests...
6. Compare `BaseClass` and `BaseClass2` line for line. If they're not identical, then refactor them to make them identical.
7. Frequently running all of your unit tests...
8. Once they're identical, change all references to `BaseClass2` to `BaseClass`
9. Remove the unused `BaseClass2`
10. Run your unit tests...

Repeat as required.

Note this is pretty much the same procedure to use when you find some common code you feel should be all a single method.

Comment: Thank you, I Like this aproach.

Comment: Arghs, that remember too much my lovely hated TDD ... :P